# How to do I purge the LiteSpeed cache using WordPress's REST API?

Tags: wordpress, rest, litespeed

I'm communicating with a WordPress site's REST API with RestSharp. I've authorised myself to the client's website and issued a GET to `https://REDACTED/wp-json/litespeed/v1/ping`. I've received a promising looking response: `{"ver":"5.3.2","_res":"ok"}`.

Now, how do I now trigger a purge_all?

Answer (score 1):

well , the answer is no ,  LiteSpeed Cache plugin doesn't have REST endpoint for purge event

best you can is use code snippet to add your own custom REST endpoint ,  something like `/wp-json/mycustom/purge_all`

and hook it to `do_action( 'litespeed_purge_all' );` action for purge all